# Changing System Version

Tags: macos

In order to run this game, it says I need to be using 10.7.4 or later. So I changed the SystemVersion.plist file to 10.7.4, and it still gives me the error message, even though it says I have 10.7.4. I am running 10.6.8.

Comment: You will have to simply update your system to 10.7.4 there are far to many checks to "trick" software into running.

Comment: Also, software doesn't put a version requirement just for the fun of it. If they went through the trouble of saying that their software requires 10.7.4, then there is something in 10.7.4 that their software needs to function.

Comment: so you are saying I cant run it on my Mac classic?

Answer (score 2):

You obviously **need** 10.7.4 for whichever program, it is near to **impossible** to trick a system into thinking it's a different version. Whichever way it probably needs something in 10.7.4, the     system requirements aren't just there for the *LOLs*. Just update!

Answer (score 1):

Like all OS companies, Apple releases new code, new APIs in their software at a regular rate. What most likely happened is the code uses the BrightAndShinyFunction() that was just released in 10.7.4. The code will check for the presence of BrightAndShinyFunction(), and it will bail if its not there.

You can't just fake this. You changing the version string won't make the "Check for BrightAndShinyFunction()" work. You need to update. 10.8 has been out for a while. 10.9 (Mavericks) is in beta. If your Mac supports 10.7, you really should update to 10.7 at least. 10.6 is showing its age. It's about $20, though I do think you need to call Apple to get 10.7... only 10.8 is available directly from the Mac App store.